# Linq: how to exclude condition if parameter is null

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have some table and the following condition of query: if parameter A is null take all, if not, use it in the query. I know how to do that in 2 steps:

```
List<O> list = null;
if (A = null)
{
    list = context.Obj.Select(o => o).ToList();
}
else
{
    list = context.Obj.Where(o.A == A).ToList();
}
```

Is it possible to have the same as one query?
Thanks

Comment: I think you don't need the `Select()` there.

Comment: I do hope you mean `A == null`! (C# should keep that from compiling, but it's always best to make sure code posted is in proper compilable form. It's important to be critical of posted code because that *would* have compiled [but not worked as expected] in some languages.)

Answer (score 27):

How about:

```
list = context.Obj.Where(o => A == null || o.A == A)
                  .ToList();
```

You can do it in one query but still using a condition:

```
IEnumerable<O> query = context.Obj;
if (A != null)
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.A == A);
}
var list = query.ToList();
```

Or you could use a conditional operator to put the query in a single statement:

```cs
var query = A is null ? context.Obj : context.Obj.Where(o => o.A == A);
var list = query.ToList();
```

I would personally suggest either of the latter options, as they don't require that the LINQ provider is able to optimise away the filter in the case where `A` is null. (I'd expect most good LINQ providers / databases to be able to do that, but I'd generally avoid specifying a filter when it's not needed.)

Comment: This way the condition `A == null` would be evaluated for every item of the collection, although more readable I don't think it is totally correct.

Comment: @AS-CII, not necessarily. That would be the case for LINQ to objects. But this query looks like LINQ to SQL or something similar.

Comment: @svick - Good point. Anyway I think it's something that shouldn't be part of the `Where` clause. I mean, is the nullability check of a client variable meaningful for the query?

Comment: @AS-CII: It's possible that the LINQ to SQL translation would notice that this is a constant "true" value and not send up the value or even any of the where clause. I'm not saying this is particularly nice - just that it's what was asked for.

Comment: While this answer can be correct, is not useful at all.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli: I've provided two ways of achieving what was required. In what way is it "not useful at all"? (Note that 22 people *do* think it's useful...)

Comment: @JonSkeet this will bring all the data into a list and then filter it inside or will execute after conditions setted? I think Mladen answer is better in this case. I don't understand the substancial difference between your "two answers"

Comment: @LeandroBardelli: The first approach will always have the filter, and assumes that whatever is performing the filtering will be able to optimize. That's roughly equivalent to Mladen's answer. The second approach makes the filtering itself conditional. In neither case is everything fetched to a list first.

Answer (score 9):

I opted for

```
var list = context.Obj.Where(o => A.HasValue ? o.a == A : true);
```

Comment: solved my problem. when you have null able parameters for controllers actions.

Comment: Also note that this only works if `A` is a `Nullable<T>` rather than (say) a `string`. We don't know the type here...

Comment: Ah good point, thanks @JonSkeet!

Answer (score 3):

I would probably write the query like this:

```
IQueryable<O> query = context.Obj;
if (A != null)
    query = query.Where(o => o.A == A);
var list = query.ToList()
```

It's not one expression, but I think it's quite readable.

Also, this code assumes that `context.Obj` is `IQueryable<O>` (e.g. you are using LINQ to SQL). If that's not the case, just use `IEnumerable<O>`.