# LINQ WHERE statement/ignore conditions

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements, where-clause

I need to ignore some or all conditions in WHERE statement if parameter is null or empty
F.E:

I have simple LINQ query

```
var query = from x in context.a
            where x.p == param1 && x.i == param2
            select x;
```

How can I ignore `x.p == param1` if param1 is null or emty?

### EDIT

Tried this

```
var query = from myLog in myContext.ApsValidationLogs
            where (myLog.systemtype == comboBoxSystemType.SelectedItem.ToString() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxSystemType.SelectedItem.ToString()))
              && (myLog.bankid == comboBoxBankId.SelectedItem.ToString() || string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxBankId.SelectedItem.ToString())))
            select myLog;
```

But got

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

In case if second combobox's item is null. What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq: how to exclude condition if parameter is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438382/linq-how-to-exclude-condition-if-parameter-is-null)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add it as a condition:

```
 var query= from x in context.a 
            where String.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) || (x.p == param1 && x.i == param2)
            select x;
```

If `param1` is null or empty, the condition will always be true, which effectively "ignores" the where conditions entirely.

Answer (score 6):

you can individually check `param1` and `param2`  this one..

```
var query = from x in context.a
             where (X.p==param1 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1))
             && (X.i==param2 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
             select x;
```

the above two conditions also works well , if you want to check individually