# How to ignore particular condition in LinQ

Tags: conditional-statements

I have a linq as below:

```
var finalist = (from b in GeneralAction.EM().Vwmembersummarydetails
                where selectedPersonId.Contains(b.Id)
                select new GeneralCommonFunctions.MemberDetailSumary
                {
                  Index = 0,
                  ProjectText = string.Join(", ", (from d in GeneralAction.EM().Member_has_properties
                                                   join e in GeneralAction.EM().Properties on d.Property_id equals e.Id
                                                   where d.IsDeleted == 0 && d.Member_id == b.Id && e.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId)
                                                   select e.Project.Description).Distinct().ToArray()),
                  PropertyText = string.Join(", ", (from f in GeneralAction.EM().Member_has_properties
                                                    join g in GeneralAction.EM().Properties on f.Property_id equals g.Id
                                                    where f.IsDeleted == 0 && f.Member_id == b.Id && g.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId)
                                                    select g.LotNum).ToArray()),
                  PurchasePrice = GeneralCommonFunctions.GetTotalPurchasePriceByProjectType(b.Id, projectTypeId),
                  Name = b.Name,
                  Email = b.Email,
                  }).AsQueryable();
```

I would like to ask that, how to ignore these two conditions:

**e.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId)**

**g.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId)**

when the projectTypeId is null or 0.

Comment: Are you familiar with the ternary operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ WHERE statement/ignore conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456997/linq-where-statement-ignore-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the conditions, simply use logical or:

```
(projectTypeId == null || Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId) == 0 || e.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId))
```

To call the different functions, use the tertiary operator. Note that this may not work with Linq to SQL -

```
(projectTypeId == null ? GeneralCommonFunctions.GetTotalPurchasePrice(b.Id) : GeneralCommonFunctions.GetTotalPurchasePriceByProjectType(b.Id, projectTypeId))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in your own words -

> e.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId)
>
> g.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId)
>
> when the projectTypeId is null or 0.

So, convert that english sentence into code.

```
&& e.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId)
```

will become -

```
&& ((e.ProjectType_id != null && e.ProjectType_id != "0") ? e.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId) : true)
```

You can then optimise it more as @netmage mentioned -

```
(projectTypeId == null || Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId) == 0 || e.ProjectType_id == Convert.ToInt32(projectTypeId))
```

And similarly,

> How to call GeneralCommonFunctions.GetTotalPurchasePrice() when projectTypeId is null and call GeneralCommonFunctions.GetTotalPurchasePriceByProjectType() when projectTypeId is not null.

Similarly becomes -

```
PurchasePrice = projectTypeId = null ? GeneralCommonFunctions.GetTotalPurchasePrice(...) : GeneralCommonFunctions.GetTotalPurchasePriceByProjectType(b.Id, projectTypeId),
```

Comment: I have found my question is actually duplicated. Anyway thanks for your answer.