# How to pass variable null in entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

How do i pass a variable in the entity where, when this variable is null or empty, the query returns all data to me.

Example:

```
 public IList<Pessoas> Pessoas { get; set; }

 Pessoas = await _context.Pessoas
                 .Where(s => s.Nome == nome)
                .ToListAsync<Pessoas>();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194/conditional-linq-queries, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438382/linq-how-to-exclude-condition-if-parameter-is-null,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double pipes(or ) `||` operator.

```
Pessoas = await _context.Pessoas
                 .Where(s => s.Nome == nome || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome))
                .ToListAsync<Pessoas>();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Then you should mark the answer as well.

Comment: How to do this with int variable ??

Comment: Integer variable will contains Zero as default value so that you can check for zero in or condition

Comment: But then, how do I do to return all values without doing an if ??

Comment: lets say nome is of type integer. then its default value will be 0. if nothing assigned to that variable and if you want all records then your condition should be lie "s.Nome == nome || nome==0"

Comment: But then in this example, when I put, "name == 0" it returns me values that are null in the database that are saved as default 0, and the ones that really have value it does not.

Comment: have you tried? we are not using "s.Nome==0"(column name) we are using "namo==0" variable directly.

Comment: solved I put example "name> = 0", then it searches for all values. Thanks a lot for the help. Hugs

Answer (score 0):

i guess you can try something like

```
public IList<Pessoas> Pessoas { get; set; }

Pessoas = await _context.Pessoas
                 .Where(s => s.Nome == nome|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome))
                .ToListAsync<Pessoas>();
```