# foreach with where and condition if parameter exists

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a large query from which I'm trying to get data using the `Where` condition with the parameters `StudentName` and `StudentSurname`, which is set by the user through a search form.

If `StudentName` and `StudentSurname` has values, everything is fine, but if one of them does not have a value, then I receive nothing.

Problem is that in such case I want this foreach loop to get data anyway without the parameters that are null.

```
foreach (var item in innerJoinQuery.Where(item => item.StudentName == StudentName 
                                               && item.StudentSurname  == StudentSurname)
```

Comment: Do you mean the input values are not provided (i.e. `StudentName` is null) or the data is not there, i.e. `item.StudentName` is null?

Comment: yes. when you hit search but do not fill the search box of StudentName or StudentSurname  .

Comment: Then you need to return all the data from database?

Comment: In that case you case just validate like this :  string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentName) which returns boolean value

Comment: Yes I want to return data anyway. And if one of variables is null then foreach gives nothing. But I want it to return at least all data with second option

Comment: Kamala HB can you write foreach string complete so I can understand ?

Comment: try this => `foreach (var item in innerJoinQuery.Where
(item => (item.StudentName == null || item.StudentName == StudentName) && 
(item.StudentSurname == null ||  item.StudentSurname  == StudentSurname)  )`

Comment: try `item => (item.StudentName == StudentName || string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentName )) && (item.StudentSurname  == StudentSurname || string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentSurname))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438382/linq-how-to-exclude-condition-if-parameter-is-null this question has your answer

Comment: thanks all of you for help, I've checked Nisarg Shah solution and it suits me just fine. Thanks all!

Comment: @David Can you first tell me which field you ant to check whether it is null or not? whether StudentName or item.StudentName ? Can you post your sample code?

Comment: Kamala HB I want to check StudentName and StudentSurname whether they have some value or not, and if they do then use them in foreach. Nisarg Shah wrote solution and it works perfect. I've checked it already. Thank you Sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq: adding conditions to the where clause conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884651/linq-adding-conditions-to-the-where-clause-conditionally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put an OR condition allowing an item to pass if one of the search parameters is null or empty. Something like:

```
innerJoinQuery.Where(item => 
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StudentName) || item.StudentName == StudentName) 
    && 
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StudentSurname) || item.StudentSurname  == StudentSurname)
)
```

Comment: You can put every `or` condition in the separated `Where` function, will be much more readable

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentName))
    innerJoinQuery = innerJoinQuery.Where(item => item.StudentName == StudentName);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StudentSurname))
    innerJoinQuery = innerJoinQuery.Where(item => item.StudentSurname == StudentSurname);

foreach (var item in innerJoinQuery)
...
```

Comment: I find this cleaner than Nisargs solution, easier to read, even though they're both essentially the same